# What do each of the bits in a 24-bit bmp image header signify?

Tags: bmp

I am picking apart the 24-bit bitmap image format. So far, I have found that the 35th byte indicates the number of pixel bytes and that the pixel bytes begin at the 55th byte.

What I cannot understand is what dictates the values of the 3rd, 4th, and 19th bytes.

For clarification, this is the 24-bit bitmap used by Microsoft Paint, recognized by Windows 10.

Comment: You need to edit your question so that it makes sense. "35th byte India ages"?

Comment: You say "**the** 24-bit bitmap image format." There are many 24-bit bitmap image formats. Please be more specific which one you are studying. Most of them are documented; you shouldn't need to reverse-engineer them.